How estimate utility function and risk aversion level for an investor from empirical data?
Suppose we are interested in estimating utility function for an institutions. We have collected P&L data from different trades, and are interested to estimate some $u(P\&L;\alpha)=(P\&L)^{\alpha}$ utility function's parameter, namely $\alpha$. As we do not observe both $u(P\&L;\alpha)$ (values of utility function) and the parameter $\alpha$, this is kind of problematic problem (seems to me). Do you have any thoughts how to handle with this problem?
P.S. I think one may use holding period to estimate $\alpha$, though not sure.

Utility parameters usually depends on the utility function you specify which is usually a function of wealth or better consumption and not P&L. Also your utility function is weirdly defined and has no decent microfoundation. I would need some more details.
From a structural approach these are two very good references in estimating risk aversion and elasticity of intertemporal substitution:

Calvet et al. The Cross-Section of Household Preferences (2022)
Choukhmane & de Silva What Drives Investors’ Portfolio Choices? Separating Risk Preferences from Frictions (2024)

If you are looking to estimate specifically for institutions, then you should look into the work of Koijen & Yogo, who start from a mean-variance problem and estimate how certain institutions "like" certain characteristics. Here's the reference:

Koijen & Yogo A Demand System Approach to Asset Pricing (2019)

Either way your question needs more details.

Actually, when i use "utility" function, i mean "value" function. I changed wording to keep things simple. And value can be a function of P&L, and no need to evaluate value relative to wealth. Value function's reference point is 0. Moreover, functional form that i presented is classical and well-documented.

If it's classical and well documented please provide references.

E.g., https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w18621/w18621.pdf . Page 33, Figure 1.
